# converting sql stored procedure int sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I work on old project which contain one stored procedure. i can't understand that stored procedure then what is the sql query for below stored procedure.

```
USE [Mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_SearchCAMAStructure]    Script Date: 10/19/2013 2:08:16 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SearchCAMAStructure]
@section as nvarchar(max),
@quality as nvarchar(max),
@style as nvarchar(max),
@ward as nvarchar(max),
@improvment as nvarchar(max),
@condition as nvarchar(max)
As
Begin

SET NOCOUNT ON;
--SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
Declare @Where as varchar(max)
Declare @Select as varchar(max)

Set @Select = ' Distinct vi.struct_no as structure, a.assesmt_no as assessment, o.own_last+'' , ''+o.own_first as taxpayer, id.year_built as built, id.effect_age as age, vi.aprais_val as mktvalue, a.parcel_no as parcel
                From [dbo].assessments a
                inner join parcel p on a.parcel_no = p.parcel_no
                inner join valueimp vi on vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no and (vi.status is null or vi.status = 0)
                inner join owner o on o.id = a.owner_id
                inner join imp_details id on id.improvementId = vi.id and (id.isdeleted is null or id.isdeleted = 0)
                inner join quality_details qd on qd.quality_id = id.quality_id
                inner join section_details sd on sd.section_id = id.section_id
                inner join style_details stdl on stdl.style_id = id.style_id
                inner join parcel pw on p.ward_no = pw.ward_no'

Set @Where = ' where  ( @section IS NULL OR sd.section_id = @section)
 AND (@quality IS NULL OR qd.quality_id = @quality)
 AND (@style IS NULL OR stdl.style_id = @style)
 AND (@ward IS NULL OR pw.ward_no = @ward)
 AND (@improvment IS NULL OR id.improvementId = @improvment)'

if @condition = 1 --Equal to 
Begin
Set @Where = @Where + ' and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age = ' +@improvment+ ' )'
end
else 
if @condition = 2 --Greater than or Equal
Begin
Set @Where = @Where + 'and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age > ' +@improvment+ ' )'
end
else
if @condition = 3 --Less than or equal
Begin
Set @Where = @Where + 'and (' +@improvment+ ' is null or id.effect_age < ' +@improvment+ ' )'
end

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)    

SET @QUERY= 'Select '+ @SELECT + @WHERE 
print @QUERY
EXEC   sp_executesql @QUERY , N'@section as nvarchar(max) ,@quality as nvarchar(max),@style as nvarchar(max),@ward as nvarchar(max),@improvment as nvarchar(max)',@section ,@quality,@style,@ward,@improvment

END
```

then what is the sql query for above stored procedure.

Comment: It builds a dynamic query in the `@QUERY` variable, with some variations depending on a parameter, and then runs it. Just follow the statements, how hard can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about all parameters passed this stored proc but this may be equivalent to below script, just replace parameters with proper values

```
SELECT Distinct vi.struct_no as structure, 
       a.assesmt_no as assessment, 
       o.own_last ,
       o.own_first as taxpayer,
       id.year_built as built, 
       id.effect_age as age, 
       vi.aprais_val as mktvalue, 
       a.parcel_no as parcel
From [dbo].assessments a
inner join parcel p on a.parcel_no = p.parcel_no
inner join valueimp vi on vi.assesmt_no = a.assesmt_no and (vi.status is null or vi.status = 0)
inner join owner o on o.id = a.owner_id
inner join imp_details id on id.improvementId = vi.id and (id.isdeleted is null or id.isdeleted = 0)
inner join quality_details qd on qd.quality_id = id.quality_id
inner join section_details sd on sd.section_id = id.section_id
inner join style_details stdl on stdl.style_id = id.style_id
inner join parcel pw on p.ward_no = pw.ward_no
WHERE 
( @section IS NULL OR sd.section_id = @section) AND 
( @quality IS NULL OR qd.quality_id = @quality)  AND 
( @style IS NULL OR stdl.style_id = @style) AND
( @ward IS NULL OR pw.ward_no = @ward) AND
( @improvment IS NULL OR id.improvementId = @improvment) AND
1 = (CASE 
     WHEN  @condition = 1 AND ( @improvment is null or id.effect_age = @improvment) THEN 1
     WHEN  @condition = 2 AND ( @improvment is null or id.effect_age > @improvment) THEN 1
     WHEN  @condition = 3 AND ( @improvment is null or id.effect_age < @improvment) THEN 1
     END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some parameters what your giving when going to execute this stored procedure.

```
@section as nvarchar(max),
@quality as nvarchar(max),
@style as nvarchar(max),
@ward as nvarchar(max),
@improvment as nvarchar(max),
@condition as nvarchar(max)
```

And you have two portion of your sql query, one is in @Select variable and another is on @Where variable.
@Select holds the joining and selected column names and you are making @Where clause based on the @Condition input.
Here string concatenation has been used, you can google for more on string concat in sql server.
Finally you are making your full query with @Select and @Where clause in

```
SET @QUERY= 'Select '+ @SELECT + @WHERE
```

And the printing and executing the query.